# What `uhelper` option in `fstab` means?

Tags: mount, fstab

When we run `mount` we can see:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/kes/A49C24B59C2483C0 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

What does `uhelper` option mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It tells `umount` that it should use the program `umount.udisks2` to unmount that file system. That allows ordinary users to unmount without needing root privileges.

Comment: Is this the option which cause `unmount` button to appear? [screenshot](http://joxi.ru/n2YB4X5cjxbEZA)